# Is there only one way to get session in java calling request.getSession()?

Tags: java, session

I like to know is there only one way to call session using `request.getSession()` or is there any other way?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't like `request.getSession()`? Is it unsuitable for what you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The api shows two methods. Basically one creates the session for you if needed, and the other doesn't.

http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28%29

and

http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28boolean%29

Comment: He might not be expecting this. But its fair enough. +1

Answer (score 0):

If you're thinking of something like `MagicSessionSignleton.getSession()`, that can be called from anywhere in the code, unfortunately there isn't. You can however, build a filter that does that for you (or use a framework that provides simple access to the request/session context).